# Automation Testing Webview2 application using RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, testing, robotframework, webview2

I have an application developed using webview2.
It is a web application that would be driven by Microsoft Edge(Chromium). It would give a feel of Native/Desktop app
instead of web app to the end user.

I want to automate testing for this app using Robot framework. I have tried desktop libraries for scripting the test
cases but I am facing issue while locating the elements on screen.

I have tried Zoomba, Sikuli, Flaui, White but each one is failing, but when I researched more in this component I found an documentation which uses Dotnet, Selenium and Edge drivers for testing it.

Can someone help how can we write below code in Robot to test the same using Selenium Library:

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions(false, "webview2");
edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\path\to\your\webview2\project.exe";
string msedgedriverDir = @"C:\path\to\your\msededriver.exe's\directory";
string msedgedriverExe = @"msedgedriver.exe";
EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(msedgedriverDir, msedgedriverExe, false);

EdgeDriver e = new EdgeDriver(service, edgeOptions);
e.Url = @"https://www.microsoft.com";
e.Quit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have a solution for you to try.

This has been merged to master and can be installed with:

> pip install robotframework-zoomba --upgrade

I have a demo script using the sample application provided by microsoft located in [~/samples/WebView-DesktopTest.robot](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/samples/WebView-DesktopTest.robot). This script shows how to open the application, control the webview layer, and also control the application layer.

[Example in action](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3010366/122806407-e4759700-d28f-11eb-8b72-779660606d9f.gif)

[Let me know on the github issue](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/issues/203) if this ends up working for you.